# Vertical centering using negative margins, works in Safari but not in Firefox/Chrome, any ideas?

Tags: html, css, positioning, center, vertical-alignment

I've been searching to find someone who has had a similar problem to me:

http://dominicburton.co.uk/soas/

The website I'm working on renders fine in Safari but not in Chrome or Firefox.

Firefox sees the style but only renders the negative top margin not the top:50%.

```
#wrapper {
margin-top: -245px;
position: relative;
top: 50%;
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I've pretty much run out of ideas...

Comment: Why to use `margin-top:-245px` and `top:50%` ?

Comment: I want the content to be vertically centred on the page and the height of the content is 490px.

Comment: Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use absolute positioning, add a height and margin should be half the height negated. Check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/CYKwM/

```
#wrapper {
    height:490px; /* you need to specify a height*/
    width:490px;
    margin-top: -245px; /*negative half the height*/
    position: absolute; /*change to absolute*/
    top: 50%;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but that big red box seems to pulsate. :o

Comment: @shaz i think it's your monitor refresh rate, you can give me a +1 for answering your question :-)

Comment: @Shaz: It's probably the result of a low cost monitor.

Answer (score 0):

**[Vertical Align Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/4XU6A/)**

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {height:490px;
margin-top: -245px; /* Negative Half Height */
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
}
```

[**Source**](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)

This should be relatively easy to implement, your DIV layout is basically 100% there,

P.S. nice design man!

Comment: Thanks! I've added the table and cell structure, but it seems to be aligning to the top for some reason. Does it matter whether the child divs are positioned absolutely or relatively? Does the height of the wrapper need to be set?

Comment: @Dom - It doesn't need a height - that is the advantage of this method, however if it is a certain height there is another method? Wrapper I believe should be set to 100% - ill do up a fiddle for you.

Comment: Just managed to solve it using the suggestion above, thanks anyway though.